# Perfromance Issue - Dispatcher Servlet in Spring MVC is taking more time

Tags: spring-mvc

Dispatcher Servlet in Spring MVC is taking more time which increases overall response time of the request.Can you please give me some tips to reduce time taken by DispatcherServlet? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Currently your question contains too little information, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then rephrase/improve your question.

Comment: The debug logs are on maybe?